# is the collection returned by sql predicate from a hazelcast map unmodifiable?

Tags: java, hazelcast

is the collection returned by sql predicate from a hazelcast map unmodifiable?  I am trying to  add to the set which I receive from the sql predicate (on a hazelcast map) - I just need to confirm whether its modifiable or whether its my code which is causing the issue.

```
Set<UDC> testSet = new HashSet<UDC>();
testSet = (Set<UDC>) testMap.values(new SqlPredicate("testUUID != " + id + " AND testStatus = 1"));  //Set is not empty!
```

Any add operation on the set is throwing an UnsupportedOperationException.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we see the exception?

Comment: thanks - it is unmodifiable - I'll update the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my initial testing, the set returned from the SQLPredicate is unmodifiable.  I could not find any option to retrieve a modifiable set using the sqlpredicate (using hazelcast-2.5).  I would be quite glad if I'm wrong! Hope it helps.

Comment: It's expected that it is unmodifiable since any value retrieved from distributed in memory grid is not backed. That means that any changes to it will not be reflected in in-cache instance of it, you need to put changed value back to cache.